# Vuex Can't Import File with “...”

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, ecmascript-6

---

I am using Vuex in my app. And I am trying to import `router` in `store/modules/auth.js`. However, I am not able to pull it as it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/store/modules/auth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.../routes/routes.js' in 'c:\wamp64\www\test\resources\assets\js\store\modules'
```

I import `router` using:

`import { router } from '.../routes/routes.js'`

My folder structure is like this:

```
├── _ js
    ├── _components     
    ├── _routes
    |   └── routes.js
    ├── _store
    |   |── _modules
    |   |   └── auth.js // Here I import the router
    |   └── store.js
    ├── App.vue
    └── main.js
```

`.` will go to `modules`. `..` will go to `store` & `...` should go to the root folder, isn't it? Still, I am getting the error. Please help!

Comment: `../../`, not `...`. There's no such thing as `...`.

Comment: @BillCriswell Can you please explain how that `../../` works or give me a resource(link) so that I can understand better?

Comment: It essentially boils down to this: `./` is the current directory, `../` is the parent directory, you can chain this together is much as you want. `/` is *web*root, this is typically where your `index.html` file lives but it's best to avoid this so webpack can process the urls.

Comment: http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html this may also be useful.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import { router } from '../../routes/routes.js'
```

Comment: If possible, can you elaborate how it works actually?

Comment: .../ means one directory down

Comment: It should be `../../` for this question!

Comment: so if .../ means one directory down, what does ../../ mean?